# Consulta no me trae datos al presionar boton ASP

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net

Muy bien tengo un formulario, una tabla, un boton y una caja de texto, la tabla me aparece vacia al parecer no busca los datos, (Pd la consulta manualmente si fucniona),pero supongo que mi error es en la consulta, pero no estoy seguro...

**hc.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txt_clave_curso" name="clave_curso"  runat="server" ReadOnly="false" Text=""></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="btn_search" name="btn_search" runat="server" Text="  Aplicar  " CausesValidation="true"  CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-sm" Width="140px" />

<Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_search" EventName="Click"/>
        </Triggers>
```

El trigger anterior actualiza la tabla con los datos cuando presiono el boton..

**vb.hc.aspx Aqui ya empieza la parte de la BD**

```
Protected Sub rg_hhc_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles rg_hhc.NeedDataSource
        Dim dbConn As MySqlConnection
        Dim dbComm As MySqlCommand
        Dim dbAdapt As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim connStr As String = Nothing
        Dim sqlQuery As String = Nothing
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim buscarclave As String = txt_clave_curso.Text 
//Aqui quiero tomar lo que tiene la caja de texto para buscarlo en la consulta

connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("X").ConnectionString
dbConn = New MySqlConnection(connStr)





dbConn.Open()
```

Parte resumida de la consulta, al final tengo un LIKE que no me funciona para buscar...

```
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " where b.fecha_ef>='2018-09-01' and b.fecha_ef<='2018-09-30' and a.Id_org='PNGR' and a.Id_detalle>0  and c.Idcurso like '%'" + buscarclave + "'%'"
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " group by a.Idlista"


    dbComm = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConn)
    //Aqui en dboParameters no se si lo lleva o no 
    dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Idcurso", buscarclave)
    dbAdapt = New MySqlDataAdapter(dbComm)
    dbAdapt.Fill(table)
    dbConn.Close()
    dbConn.Dispose()
    rg_hhc.DataSource = table
    table.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Creo que tu consulta con el like tiene unas comillas simples que estan demas, no deberia ser asi: `sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " where ...  and c.Idcurso like '%" + buscarclave + "%'"`

Comment: Me muestra todos los datos en mi tabla, pero al momento que presiono el boton recarga pero me trae todos los datos de igual forma

Comment: ¿Y cuando presionas el boton la variable `buscarclave` tiene valor?, ¿Cuando presionas el boton, la consulta te devuelve datos?, ¿Ya depuraste paso a paso?

Comment: Cuando presiono el boton se recarga la tabla y no me busca nada, aparecen todos los datos, como puedo ver si realmente lleva datos la variable?

Comment: Coloca un stop, te dejo el siguiente enlace: [Navegar por el código con el depurador de Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)

Comment: mmm solucionado, tenia mal la variable de busqueda y ademas duplicadas